# Only one Dropzone working when multiple dinamically initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm writing a web application where I need to initialize multiple dropzones basing on server content, I currently have a code similar to this:

```
<script src="/js/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script>
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
window.dropzones = {};


function checkDropzones(container) {
    var possibleDropzones = container.querySelectorAll('.needs-to-be-dropzoned');
    possibleDropzones.forEach(function (zone) {
        if (zone.id.length === 0) {
            zone.id = 'dropzone_filled_' + (new Date()).getTime();
            window.dropzones[zone.id] = new Dropzone(
                '#' + zone.id,
                {
                    paramName: 'image',
                    addRemoveLinks: true,
                }
            );
        }
    })
}

function renderServerContent() {
    window.customSections.forEach(function (custom_section) {
        var container = document.getElementById(custom_section);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/customRenderUrl?section=' + custom_section,
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            success: function (response) {
                container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + response.component;
                if (response.component_type === 'image_uploader') {
                    checkDropzones(container);
                }
                // ... other marginal stuff ... 
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        })
    })
}

// ... other scripts ... 

window.customSections = [/* server stuff */];
renderServerContent();
</script>
```

Basically, I have some stuff to dynamically render from the server, so I send a request asking for component rendered data and when I get the answer-back, I check if the inserted content contains an element with `.needs-to-be-dropzoned`, if so, I assign it a time-based ID (component rendering has a delay between each component so the IDs are unique) and instance the dropzone. This works well with just one dropzone, but when multiple are on the same page it won't generate errors but will work for just the last element on the page.

The server content is something like this:

```
<form
    class="col-12 container-fluid pb-2 dropzone needs-to-be-dropzoned"
    method="POST"
    action="/imageUploadUrl"
>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="..." >

    <div class="dz-default dz-message">
        Upload files
    </div>
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name=image" type="file" />
    </div>
</form>
```

If I launch a `console.dir(window.dropzones)` I get 2 objects:

```
Object { dropzone_filled_1624370363574: {…}, dropzone_filled_1624370363803: {…} }
​
dropzone_filled_1624370363574: Object { element: form#dropzone_filled_1624370363574.col-12.container-fluid.pb-2.dropzone.needs-to-be-dropzoned.dz-clickable, version: "5.9.2", clickableElements: (1) […], … }
​
dropzone_filled_1624370363803: Object { element: form#dropzone_filled_1624370363803.col-12.container-fluid.pb-2.dropzone.needs-to-be-dropzoned.dz-clickable, version: "5.9.2", clickableElements: (1) […], … }
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: "*I assign it a random ID*" - `'dropzone_filled_' + (new Date()).getTime()` is not random. What debugging have you tried?  Have you checked that your IDs are truly different when generated?  What does `window.dropzones` look like, eg what does  `console.dir(window.dropzones);` show?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't mean random in a strict way, I intended random because forms haven't an ID before assigning it, by the way, there's a little delay between each component rendering so the `getTime` will assign different IDs. The `window.dropzones` contains different dropzones Objects, I'll fix the question

Comment: As I said, dropzones seem to work, the `window.dropzones` contains two dropzone Object but only the latest initialized works

Comment: Strange.  I managed to get [your code working in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/s6z4fn1L/).  2 Dropzones are created, and both work.  The only changes I made are related to faking an AJAX call on JSFiddle using their special [/echo/json/ URL](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/async-requests), and faking a server response which presumably looks something like yours.  Have a look, maybe something will jump out at you, but for now I am stumped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did various attempts to fix this, and finally, I fixed it by wrapping all server calls into promises, waited for all promises to solve and only after that, I checked for dropzones. The code is approximately this:

```
<script src="/js/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script>
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
window.dropzones = {};
window.containersToCheck = [];


function checkDropzones(container) {
    var possibleDropzones = container.querySelectorAll('.needs-to-be-dropzoned');
    possibleDropzones.forEach(function (zone) {
        if (zone.id.length === 0) {
            zone.id = 'dropzone_filled_' + (new Date()).getTime();
            window.dropzones[zone.id] = new Dropzone(
                '#' + zone.id,
                {
                    paramName: 'image',
                    addRemoveLinks: true,
                }
            );
        }
    })
}

function renderServerContent() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        window.customSections.forEach(function (custom_section) {
            var container = document.getElementById(custom_section);
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/customRenderUrl?section=' + custom_section,
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + response.component;
                    if (response.component_type === 'image_uploader') {
                        window.containersToCheck.push(container);
                    }
                    resolve();
                    // ... other marginal stuff ... 
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            })
        })
    });
}

// ... other scripts ... 

window.customSections = [/* server stuff */];
var promises = [];
promises.push(renderServerContent());
// other renderings
Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
    window.containersToCheck.forEach(function(container) {
        checkDropzones(container);
    });
})
</script>
```

This way, all Dropzones work.